# Is there a way, or tag to use, to centre any HTML element?

Tags: css, center

Is there any code or tag which can be used to centralise any HTML element? The only way I know to do this currently is to repeatedly adjust padding and margins (left) to push elements to an approximate centred position. I'm aware you can centralise text, but this doesn't appear to work for other elements such as divs, objects, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the content center of the page try to use

```
body{ margin:0 auto;}
```

to align text center use

```
p{text-align:center} or div p{text-align:center;}
```

By using HTML tag for text

```
<center>your text goes here</center>
```

you can create a class on which you can write your css like

```
<div class="align-center">Your text goes here</div>
.align-center { text-align:center; } or .align-center { margin:0 auto; }
```

so many ways are present to make the element center, its totally depends on you what layout you are creating and what kind of element you want to make center. Generally by using css we can make our elements center or as per our requirement. If you have any peculiar situation then ask.

Comment: This is the page i am working on. I'd like the facebook comments part to be centralised. 

http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10mm/youtube.html

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the code is `{text-align:center;}`.

You can do this in HTML two ways, though it is not good practice. One is `<div align='center'>`, and the other is `<center>thing to center</center>`

Answer (score 0):

For divs try:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 600px;
}

#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Basically - setting margins to auto on your wrapper div almost always works, and text-align center for the div you'd like to be centered within it.

In html

```
<center> </center>
```

works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin: 0 auto;`

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4KuRW/

Answer (score 0):

The best way from my experience to center an element is by setting up the CSS this way:

```
width: 300px; /* You actually have to set the width! */
margin: 0px auto; /* margin-top & bottom = 0, margin-left & right = auto */
```

To center the text you simpy use `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean: you have a div with id=X, height=H, width=W that you want to center horizontally and vertically relative to a parent container C (i.e. C must have be defined with position: relative)

In your CSS file, you should define the class for X like this:

```
#X{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -(W/2)px;
 margin-top: -(H/2)px;
}
```

Comment: Never use position:absolute for unnecessarily.